# Multiple people using one Shalach Manos

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot

Can a bunch of people be Yotzei their Chiyuv of Shalach Manos with one Basket? What are the Halachic requirements for doing so?

Comment: Shalach manos?  Don't you mean mishloach manos?

Comment: Do you mind if I fix it and write "mishloach manos"?

Comment: To be honest, I really don't care.  As long as people know what you are talking about.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I think Shaloch Manos is a yiddish-ism. I'm not holding in yiddish grammar, but I think it is a common way to refer to them.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I think it's acceptable the way it is. Also the tag has the more "correct" spelling. As a Yiddishism, as Double AA pointed out, I don't think it needs correcting. We don't need every question and answer to have the same linguistic and editing standards (whose would we use, anyway?) so long as they are understood by all.

Comment: @SethJ In fact, a diversity of ways of expressing a question, including different translations and transliterations of key terms, makes our content base stronger, since other people who would express the question or terms the same way will be more likely to find something here by searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Sephardi approach here from Reb Ovdiah Yosef where he allows it.

[Is the Individual Mitzvah Fulfilled If A Mishloach Manot Is Collectively Given By A Group?](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=3/23/2005)

Answer (score 2):

From [Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/h/pur/m/48968806.html):

> **May two or more people send jointly?**
>
> Yes, but the package should contain the correct quantity for each of the senders.

See there for some other caveats and conditions.